# Understanding the proof - singular matrix iff it has zero eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across the following proof:

> $A$ is singular $\iff x\mapsto Ax$ is not injective $\iff$ we can find
>   $x\neq 0$ with $Ax=0\iff 0 $ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

However, I'm not sure why

> $x\mapsto Ax$ is not injective $\iff$ we can find $x\neq 0$ with
>   $Ax=0 $

The fact that it's not injective means that **some** arguments are mapped to the same value - we don't know what are those arguments that get mappped to the same value, or what that value is. - it doesn't have to be zero. If I'm wrong, then how can we prove it?

Comment: Matrices are linear maps, and a linear map is injective iff its kernel is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point here is linearity of $x\mapsto Ax$.

If this map is not injective, there exists $y\neq z$ such that $Ay=Az$, ie $A(y-z)=0$ by linearity. So $x=z-y$ is a non-zero vector such that $Ax=0$.

Conversely, if there exists $x\neq 0$ such that $Ax=0$:

Let $y$ some vector and $z=x+y$. As $x\neq 0$, $y\neq z$ and $Az=A(x+y)=Ax+Ay=0+Ay=Ay$. Thus $A$ is not injective.

Comment: One question - what linearity? $AB-AC = A(B-C)$ is a general property of matrix multiplication.

Comment: The linearity of the map $T: x\mapsto Ax$, which is the linear map that $A$ represents.

Answer (score 4):

> $x\mapsto Ax$ is not injective $\iff$ we can find $x\neq 0$ with
>   $Ax=0 $

Means that there exist $x \neq y$ such that $Ax=Ay$

Which means

> $A(x-y)=0$ though $x-y \neq 0$

The opposite comes from

> $\exists X$ such that $AX\neq 0$ though $X\neq0$.
>   Putting $X=x-y$ for some $x,y \in V$ makes $A$ not to be injective.

Here, $V$ denotes the given vector space.

Comment: No need to use linearity whatsoever, +1.

Comment: @GitGud No need to use linearty, except of course for the part where $Ax = Ay$ implies $A(x-y)=0$...

Comment: No need to put $X = x-y$ (I'm not even sure how you chose these $x$ and $y$), just say that $AX = 0 = A0$ even though $X \neq 0$, so the map is not injective.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I just put $x$, $y$ randomly for convenience to see that $A$ is not injective.

Comment: Since $A0=0$ the opposite is trivial.

Comment: @5xum Isn't $AB+AC = A(B+C)$ a general property of matrix multiplication? We can take $B$ and $C$ to be vectors $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @user5539357 Indeed, it is a property of matrix multiplication. But that property is a consequence of linearity, so this answer still uses linearity. That was my point.

Comment: @5xum That property doesn't use linearity, but rather linearity is a consequence of the given property.

Comment: @GitGud A bit of a chicken-and-egg discussion here if you ask me. Whatever. $Ax-Ay = A(x-y)$ is a direct consequence of the fact that $A$ is linear, so you saying "no need to use linearity" is kind of strange.

Comment: @5xum I disagree. If you're asked to prove that the function $f$ given by $x\mapsto Ax$ is linear, you don't say "$f$ is linear because it is", you say "$f$ is linear because, among other things, it satisfies the property $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ *and* it satisfies this property **because** $A(x+y)=Ax+Ay$. It's a consequence of this, regardless of how trivial a consequence it is.

Comment: @GitGud I'm obviously missing the point here. From what I see, you are trying to prove: "If $A$ is linear, then $A$ is not injective iff there exists some $x\neq 0$ such that $Ax=0$". And this statement is proven (the left-to-right direction) by taking $x\neq y$ such that $Ax=Ay$, then using linearity of $A$ to show that $A(x-y)=0$.